# Ways to call JavaScript Functions

Tags: javascript, function, call, function-call

How can I call a JavaScript function when a div's display is set to none?

This is the code I have :

```
if(document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display == "none"){

myFunction();

}
```

I was thinking having a function that repeats everytime (similar to an actionscript ENTER_FRAME event) with the if statement within it but i imagine that would ass a lot of lag.

Sorry if Im not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 2 options.

1. What you have above being called with setInterval.

Or

1. Since you're waiting on a programatic event, why don't you call myFunction the same time you show myDiv?

Comment: 1. I was thinking of using setInterval but, as JoJo said, its not going to be processor efficient          2. the div's are already loaded and I want to call the script only when the user clicks a button turning a div to invisible(its a quite complicated script)

Comment: Process, shmrocessor... it's running on the client, isn't it. It doesn't have to poll every millisecond and javascript runs super fast. I don't see it as a problem if there's no other solution. I would lean towards option 2 if possible

Comment: Don't go to the dark side, Shahmeer. Resorting to polling is a sign of bad code structure. Fear leads to anger, anger leads to hate, hate leads to suffering, suffering leads to the Dark Side.

Comment: Release your anger, Shahmeer.... wait no. Actually I agree, I wouldn't do it that way. Seriously, try the other option if at all possible!!! <- that's 3 exclaimations for added exclaim

Comment: After some wrangling with the code, I went with approach number 2. Thanks for the help

Comment: Good. And may the force be with you.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a native way to listen for style changes. I would create some proxy functions. Whenever you want to hide or show the div, call these proxy functions, rather than setting the style directly.

```
function hideMyDiv() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "none";
    myFunction();
}

function showMyDiv() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
```

Coomie's suggestion of polling with setInterval would not be processor efficient.

Comment: That's the thing, the only way I can call the Proxy function is by using the built in triggers (onClick, onLoad, etc). i need a way for js to automatically detect changes on the page

Answer (score 0):

Trying to work out a useful thing to say here.

Basically, you want to try and design your software such that you don't need to try and do this sort of thing.

Probably your easiest way forward would be to adopt what JoJo's suggesting.

Another approach is to add a little abstraction, so that whatever would cause the div to be hidden raises an event, one listener of the event hides the div, another does your other action.

Comment: He speaks of the observer pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern . It may or may not be the way to go depending on the complexity of your project.